# Notificando o Browser via backend

Tags: c#, .net, navegador-de-internet, signalr, notificação

Então, estou fazendo um método que gera um pdf, mas como o arquivo é grande, pensei em "avisar" o browser qndo o arquivo estivesse concluido.
Isso da pra ser feito com o Signalr?

obrigado pessoal!!
abs

Answer (score 1):

Ricardo,

O SignalR será uma feature para você estabelecer uma comunicação em tempo real com o cliente, mas o seu real problema não envolve somente isto.

Com esta implementação com SignalR, você precisa ter em mente que todo o processo:
- Iniciar o processo assíncrono para gerar o PDF
- Informar o cliente que o documento está sendo gerado
- Controlar o processo de geração do PDF e passar a informação à sua implementação do SignalR para que o cliente seja comunicado.
- Ao comunicar o cliente, iniciar processo de download (ou disponibilizar o link para baixar)

O SignalR será no seu processo somente um canal de comunicação em tempo real, toda a implementação é mais complexa do que isso.

Tem inúmeros modos de construir esta solução, acima só coloquei um cenário com o SignalR, que imagino ser algo parecido com o que pensou.